# I'm unable to increase Page loader animation time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, loader

I am trying to add a loader to my site, when I tried to run my code I noticed that the Loader animation duration was very less, so I added the JQuery code (setTimeout) and for testing, I wrote it to run for 10seconds. But it is not working. If someone could help me with this.

Github Link For Demo: https://utkarshgoel10.github.io/loader/

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #loading{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #fff url('Skateboarding.gif') no-repeat center center ;   
        z-index: 99999;
    }
    </style>
        <body onload="myFunction()">
        <div id="loading"></div>

    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function myFunction(){
                preloader.style.display = 'none';
            };

    </script>
        
    <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).load(function () {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#loading').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                });
            },4000); 
        });  
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look back at your last script. It is missing proper punctuation.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).load(function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#loading').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            });
        },4000); 
    });
}); //THIS WAS MISSING
</script>
```